# is the solution to differential Matrix Riccati Equation monotonically increasing?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I met a proof problem about the solution of the differential Matrix Riccati Equation.

$-\dot{P}(t)= P(t)A(t) + A^T(t)P(t) - P(t)B(t)R^{-1}(t)B^T(t)P(t) + Q(t)$

Where, $R(t)>0, Q(t) \geq 0$,

**My question is** :
if $ 0 \leq t_1 < t_2 \leq t_f$, 
is the claim of $ P(t_2) \geq P(t_1)$ true?

thanks